# Issue with getting url of image in Gallery

Tags: ios, swift

I'm converting the image I'm picking from the gallery into its URL like so...

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL
let imageName = imageURL?.lastPathComponent
let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
let photoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
self.localPath = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName!)

do {
   try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)?.write(to: localPath!)
   print("File Saved")
   imageArray.append(image)

   } catch { //Error }
   self.collectionView.reloadData()
   } else {  //Error here }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

Now if I have 2 images, I want to pass them one by one to my API call as a parameter. This I'm doing like so...

```
for imgURL in imageArray {
            let url = "http://myapp.com/vw/images_upload"
            let headers = [ "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]

     let Parameters =
                [
                 "image": imgURL,
                 "seller_id": id
                ] as [String : Any]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: Parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)

                .responseJSON { (response) in
                    if let httpResponse = response.response {
                        print("error \(httpResponse.statusCode)")

                        if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                            if let result = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
                                if result["success"] as! Int == 0 {
                                    print("Something went wrong!")    
                                }  else if result["success"] as! Int == 1 {
                                    print("UPLOADED IMAGE SUCCESSFULLY!!")
                              }}}}}}
```

But in the parameter, in `imgURL`, I'm not getting the url of the image. Above I had got the url in the `localPath`. But I cannot loop through `localPath` as it gives an error. Also, in the `imageArray`, I'm passing the image which is not in the url format...it is in this format: `<UIImage: 0x60800009f9f0> size {4288, 2848} orientation 0 scale 1.000000...`How the url format can be passed into the `imageArray`, that I'm not able to understand.Could this be the issue..?

Also how can I get the url of the image so that I can pass it into the API call...? Please help...

Comment: `let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage` gives you back a `UIImage`. This image is then stored in your `imageArray` by `imageArray.append(image)`. If you want to store the URLs of the images in your array, you should use `imageArray.append(imageURL)` instead.

Comment: imageArray is an array of UIImage so it throws the error 'Cannot convert value of type 'NSURL' to expected argument type 'UIImage'

Comment: If your `imageArray` is the type of `[UIImage]`, how can you expect each element as URL? You have to create a separate array for your URLs, respective to the image. And don't you have to upload the image to remote server first and then get the URL from there -> save that URL to different request.

Answer (score 0):

hi what i understand here from your question is that you are setting an image to an imageview and you want to pass that image's path to an api.
so i have written a function to do the same with a resizing ability which you can avoid or modify according to your needs.

So pass your image picked by the image picker and a default name string (eg:"image1") and you will get the image path/url in return
      func storeImage(image:UIImage, fileName:String) -> String {
        var resizedImage = image

```
     func storeImage(image:UIImage, fileName:String) -> String {
    var resizedImage = image

    if (image.size.width > 200) {
        let width = 200.0 as CGFloat
        let height = image.size.height * width / image.size.width
        resizedImage = image.scaleImage(toSize: CGSize(width: width, height: height))!
    }
    else if (image.size.height > 200) {
        let height = 200.0 as CGFloat
        let width = image.size.width * height / image.size.height
        resizedImage = image.scaleImage(toSize: CGSize(width: width, height: height))!
    }

    let imageData = NSData(data:UIImagePNGRepresentation(resizedImage)!)
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
    let docs: String = paths[0]
    let fullPath = docs.stringByAppendingPathComponent(path: fileName)

    _ = imageData.write(toFile: fullPath, atomically: true)
    return fullPath
}
```